Change Field Type in Salesforce
Can we update the Custom field type from Text to Email ? If yes, will it cause any data loss in salesforce.
Please recommend some guidelines around this to update this change to prod

Since text type has a maximum length of 255 chars & email has a maximum length of 80, it might cause data loss.
The recommended approach is to check the existing text field for length greater than 80 chars and change it before conversion.
There is an idea to increase email field length but its not in the roadmap of Salesforce.
Also , Salesforce provides official documentation for changing field types which can be checked once.

Nice. I forgot about the difference in length. Would still recommend doing a backup, in addition to manual checking. Also, the part about not being able to edit records with invalid emails.

@sfdcfox: I was about to upvote your answer. It covered points which I missed. Please restore your answer as well.

Changing the data type from Text to Email will not affect existing data in the text field. However, users will be unable to edit the record until they edit any values that are not valid emails. However, it's always recommended that you back up your data before making this kind of change, in case something does go wrong.
